# Can't connect to mongoose Error: MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a running db on mlab, however I cannot connect. This is my code:

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@ds161012.mlab.com:61012/gpbdatabase');
    const db = mongoose.connection;
          db.on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
            .once('open', () => console.log('Successfully connected to database'))
```

I am sure I am using the right username and password, it's a database user I create on Users tab at mlab. And this is my complete error statement.

> { MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds161012.mlab.com:61012] on
>   first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.78.29.56:61012]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always had these problems and it was down to mLab just being that slow and unreliable. Eventually made one for local use while developing.

Answer (score 1):

ETIMEDOUT may occurred when your database not start.

Make sure your database is started.

Comment: On mlab, it has Ok status and states that this database is up and running. So how do I start it if it isn't?

Comment: @iamnewbie I think it a good choice to test by mongo connection first like: `mongo ds012345.mlab.com:56789/dbname -u dbuser -p dbpassword` according to the official page: http://docs.mlab.com/#connect to check if there is something wrong in connection string

Comment: I have no mongodb shell offline because I am not using it. is there a mongodb shell online?

Comment: if you don't mind, can you make the test for me? this is my dummy database: 'mongodb://glenbacs:dost10wireless@ds161012.mlab.com:61012/gpbdatabase'